# SQL Sever Pivot Many Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've never used a SQL Pivot, but I think now's my chance. Problem is, I really don't know how. I've been reading documentation, but it seems like the result I want could be slightly complicated, and I can barely handle simple pivots at this point.

I have this table

```
Create table dataTable (dataID int, containerID int)
```

and I want to query it so that my result set is in the format:

```
Create table pivotTable (DataID int, Container1 bit, Container2 bit, ...ContainerN bit)
```

Where every DataID from dataTable becomes a row, and the bit-value for ConatinerN is 1 if the tuple {DataID, ContainerN} exists in dataTable, and 0 if it does not. There are 480 ContainerIDs, so I would rather not specify them all by hand, but I can if it's necessary.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Dynamic pivot example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209700/how-to-use-pivot-in-sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-joining-two-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data**

```
Create table dataTable (dataID int, containerID int)

INSERT INTO dataTable
VALUES
    (1,1),
    (2,1),
    (3,3),
    (4,2)
```

**Unique columns**

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colsWithIsNull VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY containerID ORDER BY containerID) AS RowNbr,
        CAST(containerID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS containerID
    FROM 
        dataTable
)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME('Container'+containerID),
                    QUOTENAME('Container'+containerID)),
        @colsWithIsNull= COALESCE(@colsWithIsNull + ',CAST(ISNULL('+QUOTENAME('Container'+containerID)+',0) AS BIT) AS '+QUOTENAME('Container'+containerID),
                    'CAST(ISNULL('+QUOTENAME('Container'+containerID)+',0) AS BIT) AS '+QUOTENAME('Container'+containerID))
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

**Dynamic pivot**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    dataID,
    '+@colsWithIsNull+'
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ''Container''+CAST(dataTable.containerID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ContainerText,
        1 AS isContainer,
        dataTable.dataID
    FROM
        dataTable
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(isContainer)
    FOR ContainerText IN ('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

In my case I will drop the test table:

```
DROP TABLE dataTable
```

Comment: Bingo. I already got the data I wanted out of SSRS, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pivoting the data like this doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  This is better work to be done in the data access layer of the application.  As you said, you should be returning the data set like this ...

```
{ DataID INT, ContainerNumber INT }
```

To make your life easier, only return the containers that have a `1` in the column and then fill in the gaps.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The data I have is already in the format `{ DataID INT, ContainerNumber INT }` but that's not what I want.

Comment: I'm trying to say that your database shouldn't be returning that pivoted result-set unless absolutely necessary.  This piece belongs elsewhere in an application.  That said, if you must do it use a cursor to go through all of your rows and dynamically build the query for the pivoted data.

Comment: Well it's not, this is an ad-hoc data set manually scraped together. That being said though, storing a table of roughly 500 columns where the overwhelming majority of values are zero seems pretty inefficient, and also incredibly cumbersome for basically anything other than this one-off report. 

Also I'd rather not use a cursor since I feel like this is exactly what the pivot function does, and I'd like to learn how to use it.

Comment: The pivot function requires column names for each one, so you would still need to define it.